# Could output port consist of multiple methods? (Clean Architecture)

Tags: clean-architecture

The use case output port is called by the Interactor returning the response model, and the output port could be called many times with different responses.

***Question***: Could the output port has multiple methods and the response model divided into multiple response models one for each method?

I mean to do this

```
  interface UpdateProfileOutputPort {

  void userUpdated(UserResponse user);

  void updatingUserError(String requestError);

  void validationErrors(UpdateProfileValidationErrors errors);
}
```

instead of

```
interface UpdateProfileOutputPort {
  void execute(UpdateProfileResponseModel response);
}
```

```
class UpdateProfileResponseModel{
  UserResponse user;
  String requestError;
  UpdateProfileValidationErrors errors;
}
```

Comment: Of course it could.  I assume your real question is "is this a good idea," or "does this conform to Uncle Bob's ideas for what a port should be?"

Comment: The naming you suggest makes me think you might need event listeners rather than methods here.